# Postgres Copy - Importing an integer with a comma

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I am importing 50 CSV data files into postgres.  I have an integer field where sometimes the value is a regular number (comma-delimited) and sometimes it is in quotations and uses a comma for the thousands.

For instance, I need to import both 4 and "4,000".

I'm trying:

```
COPY race_blocks FROM '/census/race-data/al.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

And get the error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1,133"

How can I do this?

Comment: You can import to a temp table such numbers as strings and then copy to a real table with apropriate conversion.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko This should be an answer, it's exactly what I was going to suggest. Only say `text` rather than "strings", since this is PostgreSQL :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you have only one column in your data.
First create temporary table with varchar column:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE race_blocks_temp (your_integer_field VARCHAR);
```

Copy your data from file

```
COPY race_blocks_tmp FROM '/census/race-data/al.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Remove ',' from varchar field, convert data to numeric and insert into your table.

```
INSERT INTO race_blocks regexp_replace(your_integer_field, ',', '') :: numeric AS some_colun FROM race_blocks_tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you! My table had multiple columns, but I was still able to use regex_replace. This is what the final step looked like (after renaming my table as a temp table and creating a new table with sales_total in real format:

insert into sales(id, product_id, manufacturer, category, product, customer_id, sale_date, sale_time, quantity, price, sale_total)
select id, product_id, manufacturer, category, product, customer_id, sale_date, sale_time, quantity, price, regexp_replace(sale_total, ',', '') :: numeric from sales_temp;

Also, storing sales_total as text (not VARCHAR) also worked.